# What does "s" represent in the formula for skewness?

Tags: self-study, normal-distribution, goodness-of-fit, normality-assumption, skewness

I need to use a test for normality for a problem.

By calculating skewness, there is a formula, which is:

$$
\text{skewness} = \frac{\sum (x_i -\bar{x})^3/n}{s^3}
$$ where $\bar{x}$ is the sample mean.

But I don't know how to calculate $s$ in the formula. What is $s$?

Comment: This formula looks wrong. Where did you get it from? Have a look at [this site](http://www.itl.nist.gov/div898/handbook/eda/section3/eda35b.htm). It is nicely explained there. Maybe you could explain more why you need a normality test? What do you hope to achieve with that?

Comment: This formula is from Paul Newbold's book. So this is not false.

Comment: You have made an error in copying the formula.  Your formula is *guaranteed* always to equal $0$.

Comment: İn the sum, I forgot ^3. $\sum (x_i-\bar x)^3 $ sorry:(

Comment: @whuber how can I calculate frequency? what is its formula? Please please please help me. I need too much:(

Comment: @COOLSerdash how can I calculate frequency ? Please please please help me. I need too much. :( please..

Comment: I'll try but I don't understand what you mean by "frequency"? What are you trying to calculate exactly? What software do you use?

Comment: I calculate by hand. For example, I have 25people. And 5 people study at [0-5] hours, 15 persons  study at [6-10] hours, 5persons study [11-15] hours. How to calculate each frequency? @COOLSerdash

Comment: @COOLSerdash in fact, I solve a question related to contingency table. There, we use (rxc) matrix, and observed frequency. How to calculate observed frequency?

Comment: Hopefully, I can explain what I want. :( @COOLSerdash

Comment: Now, do you understand me? Will I explain more? Please help me. I must do homework. And I have No time:( @COOLSerdash

Comment: No, I don't understand, I'm sorry. What exactly is the question? You have to caluclate a contingency table? The data above are the observed frequency?

Comment: Do you have a time? I write my question. Please help me.. I am a student:( I dont want to solve this. I am happy you to show a way. Thank you so much @COOLSerdash

Comment: I suggest to open a new question for this. The comments here are a bad forum for chatting. But be aware: People here won't do your homework for you. We can give you hints when you are stuck.

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/446095/i-try-to-solve-part-c my question is here. Please look at. How to calculate frequency? @CoolSerdash

Comment: I saw your helping on ME site. Thank you so much for helping. I am grateful of you :)) I solved the question thanks to you. @CoolSerdash

Comment: @Besct Just a note one using CV and the SE network more generally: Begging, of the form "*Please please please help me*" is utterly unproductive. *Everyone* here who asks a question is seeking help and everyone here providing answers is *trying* to help if they can. As someone posting a question, it's better to work on improving the question (including via research of your own, following site conventions and so on) to make it easier for people to give answers than begging in comments. Help is not given or withheld based on how much you beg.

Comment: +1. In fact, if anything begging can _reduce_ your chances of an answer. Some people delete or ignore such queries as inappropriate.

Answer (score 6):

$s$ is simply the [standard deviation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_deviation)

$s= \sqrt{\frac{\sum_{i=1}^{n} (x_i -\bar{x})^2}n}$

Comment: Really? Thank you. This did not come to my mind. By the way $\bar{x} = x_{i}/n$ right?

Comment: @Besct No, $\bar{x}=(1/n)\sum_{i=1}^{n} x_{i}$

Comment: why the downvotes?

Comment: I don't understand the downvotes: this answer looks correct to me (+1).  But it could be considered incomplete, because there are multiple conventions for the sample skewness. For instance, another convention uses "$n-1$" instead of "$n$" in the formula.

Comment: @newuser doesn't deserve these downvotes. Answer is correct and pertinent.

Comment: @sets +1 It's sometimes hard to divine what possesses someone to downvote; the only thing I can think of is that perhaps the answer is a little on the brief side, or perhaps someone was objecting to you presenting $s_n$ instead of the more usual $s_{n-1}$. But there are plenty of people around happy to vote the other way on a pertinent answer.